# Google Drive API + Refresh Token + Multiple servers

Tags: php, google-drive-api

We are using the technique described here to create a refresh token to use Google drive and store it in a config setting for `production`

- [Laravel & Google Drive Storage](https://github.com/ivanvermeyen/laravel-google-drive-demo/blob/master/README/2-getting-your-refresh-token.md)

Once we get the refresh token, we use the 3 items `client_id`, `secret_token` and `refresh_token` inside this library to write files into Google Drive and it has been working great with **ONE** server

- [Flysystem Adapter for Google Drive](https://github.com/nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive)

Once we started having multiple servers, we are getting authentication errors and we suspect that it is because of this `refresh_token` being shared on all (currently 4 servers).

Questions for folks who may have encountered this before

- Do we need to create 4 sets of `client_id`, `secret_token` and `refresh_token`?
- Do we just need one refresh token per server?

Exact error below

```
[2021-01-24 00:01:40] production.ERROR: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
 {"exception":"[object] (Google\Service\Exception(code: 401): {
 \"error\": {
  \"errors\": [
   {
    \"domain\": \"global\",
    \"reason\": \"authError\",
    \"message\": \"Invalid Credentials\",
    \"locationType\": \"header\",
    \"location\": \"Authorization\"
   }
  ],
  \"code\": 401,
  \"message\": \"Invalid Credentials\"
 }
}
 at /var/www/projectname/php/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:128)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/projectname/php/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(103): Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 [internal function]: Google\Http\REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
```

Comment: You should be able to use the same refresh token across all servers. but you will need to check when you get the response back that a new refresh token isnt also being if it is then you should update your stored refresh token.   Technically you can have up to 50 outstanding refresh tokens before they start getting expired.   However im not sure that invalid credentials is the proper error message that you would be getting for a bad refresh token.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  We have created 4 different refresh_tokens now (one for each server but same client_id and client_secret) and see how that works ... too deep to research the libraries but may have to get there if it continues to happen - thank you!

Comment: Can you confirm that the access token is indeed refreshed correctly? @ChrisGo

Comment: Because we are using the libraries, we are not sure where the access token is being saved (probably cached somewhere).  We are assuming that due to the refresh token being the same on each server, google may be expiring the previous access token if another server (using the same refresh token) asks for a new one.  The previous server would then attempt to use an expired access token that was cached earlier and invalided by the second request.  Using 4 different refresh tokens (one for each server) with the same client id and client secret seems to have fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

From our tests, it seems like you can NOT share refresh tokens across multiple servers.  We used the same client_id and same client_secret and created one refresh_token for each server and the “invalid credentials” errors went away.

So it seems like this is the solution for the process above if you are using the “exchange authorization code for tokens” method above to authenticate